# Could i restrict SQL Server Login access to only one sql server user

Tags: sql-server-2008, security

I have database and I will send it to many clients.

I set SQL Server user but could I restrict other SQL Server logins (windows authentication) for example

Comment: A different misinterpretation of this vague question could be answered by [setting the database to single-user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

By restrict I take it to mean "not allow".  Take a look at logon triggers.  More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx

There are some things you can and can't do with them but it was a fairly open ended question so you get an open ended answer.  Pretty much anything to do with restricting logon will have to happen through there.

Keep in mind however that a sysadmin login will ultimately be able to do what it wants - such as turning the trigger off.